# How to integrate CK Editor 5 with Sapper/Svelte3?

Tags: ckeditor, svelte, ckeditor5, sapper, svelte-3

I tried to integrate CK Editor 5 in my sapper project as below :

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
    
    onMount( () => {
        ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
    });
</script>

<textarea id='editor'></textarea>
```

And I got the following error :

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object. (F:\project\node_modules@ckeditor\ckeditor5-build-classic\build\ckeditor.js:5:3314)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
at Function.Module.*load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object. (F:\project_*sapper**\dev\server\server.js:8:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)

> Server crashed

How to properly integrate CK Editor 5 in sapper/svelte3 project?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [dynamic import](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Making_a_component_SSR_compatible) since there is no window on the server.

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    let ClassicEditor

    onMount(async ()=> {
        const module = await import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic')
        ClassicEditor = module.default
        ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector('#editor') )
        .then( editor => {
                console.log( editor );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
        } );
    })
</script>

<textarea id='editor'></textarea>
```

Comment: It now throws an error :✗ client
Cannot read property 'includes' of null

Comment: Works in a fresh sapper project with rollup. Can you provide a reproduction of this error?